# Mapping Outbound IPs to 1 IP in Azure App Services

Tags: azure, ip, azure-web-app-service, nat

I have 3 components of my architecture running in 3 separate Azure App Services. Each app service has 4 outbound IPs. So whenever I have to deploy my app onto the client's premise, I have to whitelist 12-16 IPs on their on-premise Firewall.

Is there any way I can deploy a NAT which uses only 1 public IP and I can provide just 1 IP to the client?

If I manage to make this architecture work then how would I modify my API calls to these services, since at the moment I'm using their 1 public IP to access their individual service, with just 1 IP how will I distinguish API calls made to different app service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regional VNet Integration for your 3 App Services:
https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/02/27/General-Availability-of-VNet-Integration-with-Windows-Web-Apps.html
Then, on the delegated subnets you can throw a User Defined Route so it goes to Azure Firewall (or any NVA) and the firewall will SNAT outbound traffic so you end up with a single outbound IP.